# Aligning an input to a divs center

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have this code

```
<div id="content1" width="400px" height="100px">
<input type="text" id="znamkyInput">
</div>

<div id="content2" width="400px" height="100px">
<input type="text" id="znamkyInput">
</div>
```

And I want the input to be **vertically centered** into the center of the div. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original html is incorrect and the div's height and width should be supplied in css (or using the style attribute).

To align in the center vertically and horizontally:

```
#content1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

As there are two of these divs immediately next to each other then `table-cell` will cause them to sit adjacent to each-other, on the same line. I would either wrap each in another div (not a great solution) or place a `br` tag between them (or some other content).

If the intention is to have several of the divs immediately next to, and below, each-other then I would consider using a table.

Comment: I am sorry but I forgot that there are 2 divs with input and if i use your code on both of them, it just aligns the bottom div next to the first div. Do you think I can fix it somehow? Really sorry for asking wrong

Comment: I've added to my answer. It depends whether there is, or will be, just two of these divs, and whether there will be anything between them.

Comment: Your <br> solution works but I had to set line-height to 0 px as if it was bigger than that, there would be empty space between divs. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this. And look at the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XB2r7/13/)

```
 #content1 {
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block on the child elements and use text-align:center on the parent. That should do the trick

```
<div id="content1" style="text-align:center" width="400px" height="100px">
    <input type="text" style="display:inline-block" id="znamkyInput">
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed the question because I think I asked wrong. I wanted co center also vertically. Although thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following,

```
 <div id="content1" width="400px" height="100px">
    <input type="text" style="display:inherit" id="znamkyInput">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="content1">
  <div>
      <input type="text" id="znamkyInput"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#content1
{
    background-color: gray;
    width:400px;
    heigth:100px;
}
#content1 div
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
   width: 158px; /*width of your input box*/
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d3UWw/4/)